# Apply Lint Task to All Subproject in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, lint

I have a multi-module project with a few Android apps and Android Library modules. It looks something like this:

```
├── awesomeapp (Android App)
├── coolapp (Android App)
└── modules 
    ├── usefulprojectA (Android Lib)
    └── usefulprojectB (Android Lib)
```

Both `awesomeapp` and `coolapp` depend on library modules:

```
implementation project(':modules:usefulprojectA:')
implementation project(':modules:usefulprojectB:')
```

What I would like to do is be able to say something like:

```
./gradlew awesomeapp:lint
```

or even

```
./gradlew awesomeapp:build
```

And have the lint task execute on `awesomeapp` and on both `usefulprojectA` and `usefulprojectB`.

Currently the lint task would only apply to the top level project, i.e., `awesomeapp`. So if I wanted to Lint the subprojects I'd have to call the lint task on the subproject directly:

```
./gradlew modules:usefulprojectA:lint
./gradlew modules:usefulprojectB:lint
```

Plus call the main project:

```
./gradlew awesomeapp:lint
```

But that's clumsy and will make my build script longer in both time and size.

So how does one apply the Lint task to subprojects too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check module and it's dependencies by adding `checkDependencies true` to your `lintOptions`:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkDependencies true
    }
}
```